# Padlock icons in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, github, tfs, visual-studio-community

my project was working good, someone asked me to upload it to GitHub, I did it and after downloaded it again, now when I open my project all of the files contained in it have a padlock icon besides and when I debug my project it produces an exception, why it this happening? Maybe it has to do with Team Foundation Server? How could I make my project work normally as it was before?[image]

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: Probably you are missing some dependency somewhere which was not correctly upload to GitHub (or TFS? not sure which source control system you used). Without [MCVE] it is not possible to suggest more...

Comment: It's called source control. And you can disassociate your project from source control through File -> Source Control.

Comment: @recursive The exception that is throwing is `"An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details."` and then the Inner Exception contains: `"The underlying provider failed on Open."` I will edit my question

Comment: @recursive I need to leave now, but I will come back in 4 or 5 hours to check it, probably is a problem with the access to the database, I'll let you know after, thanks for the answers to all of you

Comment: @AlexGH: I think it's unlikely that the padlock has anything to do with your database problem.  The padlock means the project is under version control.  That really doesn't have anything to do with the error you're having now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it was a problem of configuration, it was weird because it didn't recognized even Entity Framework, I changed to an administrator local account for windows and in the SQLServer service, right click, select Properties, Log On tab, and changed "Logon as" to "This account" with the new local account, that solved the issue

Comment: @PrakashJoshi I tried to mark it as answer but it doesn't me allow to mark it as answer because is my own answer and it asks me to wait for two days to mark it...